# In awesomewm is it possible to "pass through" all key events to an application?

Tags: x11, awesome-wm, chrome-remote-desktop

I use awesomewm with chrome remote desktop which is connected to a linux box with awesomewm as well. For the chrome remote desktop app, I'd like to send all keybindings down to the application. Instead, they get intercepted by the host.

Is it possible to enter a "passthrough" mode (when an application window is active) and send all events down to the application?

When I click on a host window, I want the host to intercept the global keybindings again.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove all global key bindings with `root.keys({})`, I think. Additionally, `c:keys({})` removes the per-client key bindings. That should get of anything that AwesomeWM intercepts.

Getting your key bindings back is just a `root.keys(your-key-binding-table)` away. (Same for the client key bindings, but I guess you don't want to restore them anyway).